# Arduino. Не получается пропинговать с компьютера через LAN(RJ-45)

Tags: arduino

Модуль ENC28J60 + Arduino Nano + Trema Shield NANO. 
Подключение через витую пару (Витая пара гигабитная). PC (192.168.0.1) - Arduino (192.168.0.2)

Через ping либо узел недоступен, либо превышен интервал.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 2);

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  byte newMac[] = {0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02};
  Ethernet.setMACAddress(newMac);  // change the MAC address
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop () {}
```

Comment: Пинг может быть без ответа по многим причинам, при этом сама сеть работает и данные передавать можно, например файрвол в антивирусе блокирует ICMP трафик, или (если я неверно понял и вы пингуете ардуину с ПК) - то может быть проблема в том что вы не разрешили ответы на ICMP трафик или ваша библиотека не умеет такого =) начните с проверки соединения со стороны ардуино в сторону ПК(ардуина = клиент, ПК - сервер)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, библиотека `Ethernet` предназначена только для родных шилдов на микросхеме W5100, W5200 или W5500. Подробности тут https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/ethernet. Для работы с ENC28J60 нужна другая библиотека.

Во-вторых, в стандартной поставке не реализован протокол `ICMP`, по которому работает `ping`. Нужна еще одна библиотека, например, эта https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ICMPPing/

В-третьих, если подключаете модуль проводами, а не надеваете стандартный шилд, в вопросе желательно указывать что куда присоединено. В этом месте тоже может быть ошибка.